# Breeze JSON Parse Error for Metadata

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I just upgraded my Breeze nuget package from 1.1.3 to 1.2.7. I was getting error about some of my classes that had "ComplexType" items, so after upgrade I am getting the error below when reading the Metadata from my MVC4 Web API. Everything was working properly before that with the exception of ComplexType, so I know for sure everything is in place, since I was getting the Metadata, and was able to show the data on the screen.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o breeze.debug.js:12561
ctor.fetchMetadata.ajaxImpl.ajax.success breeze.debug.js:12561
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
done jquery-1.9.1.js:8074
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

Comment: No idea what you are seeing, we've converted all of our samples and internal tests without an issue.  Is this failing during metadata retrieval or during your first query?

Comment: Just during Metadata retrieval. it's in line 12562:  var metadata = JSON.parse(data); I just changed this to just var metadata = data, and it worked correctly. I don't think "data" can be parsed to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and I noticed that when you issue a GET against the metadata location (/api/Context/Metadata), it returned an xml document formatted as json. I also think there is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494117/breeze-metadata-appears-in-xml-format), but in a slightly different context. In this case however, the error was raised at `ctor.prototype.fetchMetadata` in a line containing `JSON.parse()`. But I'm pretty sure is the exact same underlying cause.

Just update Breeze from Nuget (both the the dll and the js files) and that would do the trick.
Notice that you might have to manually delete the breeze files from the `/Scripts` folders.